# Timeouts for connections in C

Tags: c, networking, select, signals

**My program accepts up to 4 connections (using select function). Once they're connect, they have 5 seconds to send a string, indicating that they want to stay connected. Those that do not send within 5 seconds, or has the wrong passcode, will be disconnected.**

I've created a small timer program, that is forked whenever a connection is established. The forked timer will send back a signal to the original program if 5 seconds are gone. In which case, the signal handler will close the file descriptor, and clear the connection.

My problem is, whenever the signal handler is triggered, select() returns -1, indicating it has failed. Does anyone know why this is happening? Or if there's another timing mechanism I could use?

Thanks

Comment: What is errno when select returns -1?  That's your biggest hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the intended behavior of `select()`: return -1 with errno appropriately set if a signal occurs.

I don't think threads are the way to go here. I assume you want a program with roughly this structure (pardon the java-esque naming, but you get the point):

```
int fdsThatResponded[FDCOUNT];
memset(fdsThatResponded, 0, sizeof(int)*FDCOUNT);

while (time_elapsed < 5) {
    ret = select(......);
    if (-1 == ret) {
        handleError();
    }
    checkWhichFdAndHandleAppropriately();
    reinitializeTimerForSelectWithRemainingTime();
}
```

Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of spawning a useless thread, just keep a `lastRecvd` field associated with each socket.  Then, just give `select()` a 5 second timeout.  After select, any socket not in the select list you will need to check if it's been 5 seconds.

As for why it's failing with your current code, I suspect it's because one of the file descriptors is being invalidated.  Check `errno` and see if it's `EBADF`.